# input array as a param?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**this is my code:**

```js
    return s => counts.get(s) || 0;

// Sample call
```

I want this function to input 2 array's and on output an single array for example I call a function.

**Example:**

`f(a,b)=array` result with `a` and `b` two array

Comment: So you want to `.concat` two arrays? Please take your time and detail exactly what you mean.

Comment: why map is used when you're not even manipulating array element ?

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking. Reverting changes doesn't help clarify your intent. Do you want to add up all the numbers from arrays, or do you just want to combine the values of two arrays into one. Your code example does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the counts and map the count of given values. Then you need to udjust `undefined` values.

```js
function fn(values, counts) {
    return values
        .map(
            Map.prototype.get,
            counts.reduce((map, s) => map.set(s, (map.get(s) || 0) + 1), new Map)
        )
        .map(v => v || 0);
}

console.log(fn(["wer", "tyu", "uio"], ["wer", "wer", "tyu", "oio", "tyu"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you combine two arrays into one, Using the built in `Array.prototype.concat`

#### Solution

```js
function combineArrays (a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
}
const array1 = [1,2,3];
const array2 = [4,5,6];

console.log(combineArrays(array1, array2));
```

However, your code example doesn't seem to match what you're asking. Perhaps you want to combine all counts from both arrays into a single value?

```js
function addArrays(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}
const array1 = [1,2,3];
const array2 = [4,5,6];

console.log(addArrays(array1, array2));
```

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce